# Muliple submit button on single form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Within a form, I have two submit buttons. Depending on which button the user clicks on, I want the redirect on form.is_valid() to either be page A or page B. Do you know how I might be able to attach a different value to each submit button and pass this value on the POST request so that I can evaluate it in my view?

template.html

```
<div class="submitbutton"">
                <button type="submit">
                   Submit A
                </button>
            </div>

  <div class="submitbutton"">
                <button type="submit">
                   Submit B
                </button>
            </div>
```

views.py

```
 if request.method == 'POST':

    <!-- a bunch of code that works -->


   if user_clicked_SubmitA:     
         return redirect('profile')

   if user_clicked_SubmitB:
         return redirect('home')
```

THanks!

Comment: Can you please share the code. How your doing it.

Comment: post_data = request.POST
if '_submit1' in post_data:
 return HttpResponseRedirect("")
elif '_submit2' in post_data:
 return HttpResponseRedirect("")
elif '_submit3' in post_data:
 return HttpResponseRedirect("")
else:
 return HttpResponseRedirect("")
   
   
<form action="">
<input type="submit" name="_submit1" />
<input type="submit" name="_submit2" />
<input type="submit" name="_submit3" />
</form>

Comment: Can you put this into an answer?

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something as below

```
def my_view(request):
    post_data = request.POST
    if '_submit1' in post_data:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("")
    elif '_submit2' in post_data:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("")
    elif '_submit3' in post_data:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("")



<form action="<view_url>">
<input type="submit" name="_submit1" />
<input type="submit" name="_submit2" />
<input type="submit" name="_submit3" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't include the view_url in the action. Once I fixed that, I got your solution to work.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `name` attribute to your button :

```
<button type="submit" name="btn1" value="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button type="submit" name="btn2" value="btn2">Button 2</button>
```

and check for it in the view:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.POST.get('btn1'):
        # first button clicked
    if request.POST.get('btn2'):
        # second
```

Update: added a `value` attributes to the `<button>` tags.

Comment: This is excellent. I think this will work. Thank you! I'll test immediately.

Comment: Unfotunately, this doesn't seem to work. I thought that maybe changing the code to if request.POST.get('name') == btn1: it might work, but no luck

Comment: The buttons need a `value` attribute for this to work.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I think action also needs to be defined in the form tag, correct?